# How to replace a string with a date using awk in unix?

Tags: unix, awk

I have the following piece of code:

```
v=`date "+%Y%m%d"`
awk -F, '{$2=$v;}1' OFS=, test.txt > test2.txt
```

where `test.txt` is my input file and `test2.txt` the output file.

The lines in `test1.txt` respect the following format: `Unix,10,A`

When I execute the above script, it doubles the first and last word from test.txt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to replace the second field with the value in `$v`, you will need to pass in the value to Awk somehow.  As a separate process, Awk has no knowledge about the shell's internal variables.

```
awk -F, -v v="$v" '{$2=v}1' OFS=, test.txt > test2.txt
```

Notice also that the Awk variable's name is just `v`.  To Awk, `$v` means the input field whose number is in the variable `v`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
awk -F, '{$2=v;}1' OFS=, v=`date "+%Y%m%d"` file
Unix,20140109,A
```

You should not read variable inside `awk`
Assign them first, ten use them.

```
v=`date "+%Y%m%d"`
awk -F, '{$2=var;}1' OFS=, var="$v" file
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend the non legacy syntax here:

```
v=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
```

then you can use any of these `awk` invocations:

```
awk -F, -v v="$v" '{$2=v}1' OFS=, test.txt > test2.txt
awk -F, '{$2=v}1' OFS=, v="$v" test.txt > test2.txt
awk -F, '{$2="'$v'"}1' OFS=, test.txt > test2.txt
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the `v` variable later in the shell, you can run the `date` command from inside `awk` with either:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{"date \"+%Y%m%d\""|getline v}{$2=v}1' OFS=, test.txt > test2.txt
```

or

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{v="'$(date "+%Y%m%d")'"}{$2=v}1' OFS=, test.txt > test2.txt
```

or the inefficient

```
awk -F, '{$2="'$(date "+%Y%m%d")'"}1' OFS=, test.txt > test2.txt
```